# Debug form local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, local-storage

I have a form (demo link below).

I've tried about 8 different methods of storing the data but it won't work.

(link retracted)

The goal is, the user visits the site and fills out the form (partially or complete). They can then login if they wish.

The next time they visit the site the form should be complete (excluding password) and the avatar should display with the one stored in local storage.

I can't figure out why nothing will display, whether it's a compatibility issue or syntax issue etc.

### Problem Solved

another js script has been interfering with it causing it to fail. Resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not going to check your website for errors since you didn't provide any code. Instead I show you a quick and working way to save and read values from localStorage.

The values will be stored in key/value pairs while the key is the name of the input field.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="user" />
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
```

JS:

```
$('input').each(function() {
  $(this).on('blur', function() {
    localStorage.setItem($(this).attr('name'), $(this).val());
  });
});

for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++){
  var storageKey = localStorage.key(i),
      storageValue = localStorage.getItem(storageKey);
  $('input[name='+storageKey+']').val(storageValue);
}
```

Remeber that the for loop has to be inside of your domready function. Check the working fiddle below. Like this you have a dynamic approach for input fields - you can also do this for selects if you like to.

If you want some faster selectors you can also save the ID as key and select the input via id. Is even more dynamic.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ma6L192j/)

Edit: As requested here is an example for checkboxes/selects. It might not be the best approach but its working.

JS:

```
$('.autofill').each(function () {
  $(this).on('change', function () {
    if ($(this).is('input')) {
        if ($(this).attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                localStorage.setItem($(this).attr('id'), 'checked');
            } else {
                localStorage.setItem($(this).attr('id'), '');
            }
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem($(this).attr('id'), $(this).val());
        }
    } else if ($(this).is('select')) {
        localStorage.setItem($(this).attr('id'), $(this).find('option:selected').val());
    }


  });
});

for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
  var storageKeyElement = $('#' + localStorage.key(i)),
    storageKey = localStorage.key(i),
    storageValue = localStorage.getItem(storageKey);

  if (storageValue == 'checked') {
    storageKeyElement.attr('checked', 'checked');
  } else if (storageKey.indexOf('Select') > 0) {
    storageKeyElement.find('option[value=' + storageValue + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
  } else {
    storageKeyElement.val(storageValue);
  }
}
```

[Fiddle with Selects and Checkboxes](http://jsfiddle.net/ma6L192j/4/)

Comment: I'm assuming this won't work for checkboxes, select etc which are requirement's of the form. Is there a way to modify the above to cover all form elements?

Comment: why wouldnt this work for checkboxes? of course you have to do some adjustments.. I updated the fiddle for you - might not be the best approach and you can surely refactor the code but it works - notice: for multiple selectboxes you have to use an id containing 'Select' in my case - feel free to adjust that for your wishes.. see edit

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you have syntax error.

Change all the `mb-*` variables to `mb_*`

For example:

```
var mb-username
```

should be

```
var mb_username
```

But you have another problems in your source code too:

```
<meta name="author" content="Michael Clarke"
```

has a missing `/>` closing tag.

And you have another error:

```
ReferenceError: applySetting is not defined
```

Fix these errors, and use your console to see errors.

Comment: I have made the above fixes but still isn't working :/

Comment: Why don't you use the console to catch your errors? When I've typed a string into the usenrame, and then blur, I've got this: `ReferenceError: QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR is not defined`

Comment: I have but i cant find a solution to this, I attempted to include

  localStorage.clear();

In the try, so before storing the info it clears the old each time. But it keeps popping up the error. This is why i'm stuck each time on error goes, another appears :/

Comment: Try to use: `DOMException.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR`

Comment: That fixed the console error (just leaving the password http errors) but didn't fix the script.

Comment: Added a "test window" div to output all contents on localstorage, all values are null so it's not storing the info.

Comment: Use `localStorage.getItem('mb_username');` instead of `localStorage.mb_username`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68336/discussion-between-michael-clarke-and-lolka-bolka).

Comment: Sorry, I have no time to chat.

Comment: No problem, short story, still continuing to get the same error. 
I've tried setting up alerts so I know the functions are being called (which they are) I've seperated the call to links onclick. 

But data won't store or load, even if attempting to manually store it